# Crystal report not printing as it shows while design time when using PrintToPrinter method

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

Hi intelligent peoples,

I am stuck at a problem and I cant find solution for that anywhere on internet.

**Problem** : PrintToPrinter method does not print the same as Design. But print out is same when printing from preview of crystal report in crystal report viewers, But user don't want to click print on windows form and press print again in Print preview(Crystal Report Viewer). So basically i want to print the report directly to printer without asking user again.

**Page setup**:

> Page size is : 8.5*8.5 inches.
>   No printer(optimize for screen size) : Checked
>   Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Paper Size : Checked
>   User Defined Size : selected

Printout from CrystalReportViewer is as desired. 
But printed paper from PrintToPrinter method comes different.

Please help me,
I am stuck.

**EDIT:**
Following is the event handler for `btnPrint`.
I want user to click on `btnPrint` on Windows Form once and want the print out. No any other step.
Print comes out but not as expected.

If I open the Crystal Report Viewer on click of `btnPrint` after that user clicks on print button on Crystal report viewer and after selecting printer clicks the print button on print dialog, printer prints as expected.
But eliminating those steps doesn't prints as ago.

Hope you understood @aMazing

```cs
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBillNo.Enabled == false)
        {
            if (cmbPartyName.Enabled == false)
            {

                string strSelectPartyID = "SELECT PartyID from PartyList WHERE PartyName ='" + cmbPartyName.Text + "' AND CompanyID = " + companyID.ToString();
                con = u.connect();
                OleDbCommand cmdPartyID = new OleDbCommand(strSelectPartyID, con);
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader drPartyID = cmdPartyID.ExecuteReader();
                drPartyID.Read();
                partyID = drPartyID[0].ToString();

            }

            string strSelectBill = "SELECT * FROM BillList WHERE BillNo = " + txtBillNo.Text + " AND CompanyID = " + companyID.ToString();
            string strSelectParty = "SELECT * FROM PartyList WHERE PartyID = " + partyID.ToString();
            string strSelectItem = "SELECT * FROM ItemList WHERE CompanyID = " + companyID.ToString() + " AND BillNo = " + txtBillNo.Text;

            OleDbDataAdapter daBillList = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectBill, con);
            OleDbDataAdapter daItemList = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectItem, con);
            OleDbDataAdapter daPartyList = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectParty, con);
            DataSet dsBRSystem = new DataSet("BRSystem");
            DataTable dtBillList = new DataTable("BillList");
            DataTable dtPartyList = new DataTable("PartyList");
            DataTable dtItemList = new DataTable("ItemList");
            crpCodePrint crpBillPrint = new crpCodePrint();
            frmDemoPrint DemoPrint = new frmDemoPrint();

            daBillList.Fill(dtBillList);
            daPartyList.Fill(dtPartyList);
            daItemList.Fill(dtItemList);

            dsBRSystem.Tables.Add(dtBillList);
            dsBRSystem.Tables.Add(dtItemList);
            dsBRSystem.Tables.Add(dtPartyList);

            crpBillPrint.SetDataSource(dsBRSystem);
            DemoPrint.crvDemo.ReportSource = crpBillPrint;
            DemoPrint.crvDemo.RefreshReport();
            //DemoPrint.Show();
            //crpBillPrint.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);

            //DemoPrint.crvDemo.PrintReport();
            PrinterSettings printSetting = new PrinterSettings();
            printSetting.PrinterName = "Samsung SCX-3400 Series";


            PaperSize paperSetting = new PaperSize("Custom", 850, 850);


            PageSettings pageSetting = new PageSettings(printSetting);
            pageSetting.PaperSize = paperSetting;
            pageSetting.Landscape = false;

            crpBillPrint.PrintToPrinter(printSetting, pageSetting, true);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please SAVE the Bill first.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: So whats the problem? Is there an error? Or Just the printed output is not what you expect? Can you post some code

Comment: @aMazing,
I have edited the post.
Hope You understand my problem now..